# click a child element from a List by Tag with nightwatch

Tags: css, xpath, nightwatch.js

I have a List with my users. For example the user "root" can be find with:

```
.d-list-entry:nth-child(8)
```

but the Position in the List can change.

Is there an possibility to choose this Element by Tag?

```
    <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 268px;"><div id="user-list-objects" data-role="listview" data-selectable="single" data-auto-bind="true" data-template="userlistentrytemplate" data-bind="source: objects, events: {change: onObjectListClick}" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; min-height:200px;" class="k-widget k-listview k-selectable" role="listbox">


    <div class="d-list-entry">

        <span data-bind="text: name">copy of user2</span>
        <img id="statusIcon62c3778e-a5bd-4a81-aac5-d1c2a7b4c18c" src="status_offline_16.png" style="position:absolute; right:5px;top:6px" title="Benutzer offline" class="">

    </div>

    <div class="d-list-entry" >

        <span data-bind="text: name">hans@meier.com</span>





        <img id="statusIcon0c960a3c-7baa-4103-bb2b-4b66b06b82cd" src="status_offline_16.png" style="position:absolute; right:5px;top:6px" title="Benutzer offline" class="">

    </div>

    <div class="d-list-entry" >

            <img src="ldap_user_02_16.png" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 8px;" title="Importiert aus LDAP" class="">

        <span data-bind="text: name">jondoe</span>





        <img id="statusIcone7f5f95e-6340-42e9-9aa8-96b5ef19713d" src="status_offline_16.png" style="position:absolute; right:5px;top:6px" title="Benutzer offline" class="">

    </div>
```

Is my structure.

i want to click the text between the

tag

Comment: We'll need more information here, such as some actual code.

Comment: i updated my question with the html file i want to check.

Comment: code yourself and upload here then we can fix it.

Comment: thats my problem. i don't even have an idear how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

That´s easy,  use Xpath to find the text root then goto the parent (all with xpath), for example in nightwatch would be:

```
client.useXpath()
.click(".//text()[contains(.,"root")]/..")
```